# Local PDF hyperlinks in Windows UWP app

Tags: javascript, pdf, hyperlink, uwp, hololens

I'm writing a UWP app in javascript.
Which contains a list of links that each call a PDF.
The PDFs are stored locally in the app.
The goal is to provide a library of hands-free documentation for the Hololens (Windows AR)
Anyway I open the PDFs with:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file)
```

This all works great.
The PDFs however also reference each other with hyperlinks.
I can modify the hyperlinks to be whatever when the PDFs are originally generated.
But how can I make it so that the hyperlinks will still reference one another when opened in the user's default PDF app.
 
Again the default PDF app can be whatever.
This works fine in Adobe Acobat for Windows,
Would like to port this functionality over to UWP.

Current code and working:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("#id").onclick = function (evt) {
        pdfopen("pdf.pdf")
    }

function pdfopen(pdf) {

var imageFile = "assets\\" + pdf;

// Get the image file from the package's image directory
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(imageFile).then(
  function (file) {
      // Launch the retrieved file using the default app

      var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
      Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file)
  }
);
```

Appreciate any help in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I make it so that the hyperlinks will still reference one another when opened in the user's default PDF app.

When you use the `launchFileAsync` method without the `LauncherOptions`, it will alsway use the default app to open the .pdf files.

If you set always use the app to open .pdf files, you should be able to use the [`LauncherOptions.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.LauncherOptions#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName) to set the package family name of the target package that should be used to launch the file. Then you can add the `LauncherOptions` in the [`LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile, LauncherOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_Windows_System_LauncherOptions_) that it starts the default app associated with the specified file, using the specified options.

For example for use the Edge to open .pdf files:

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";
Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(
  function(success) {
    if (success)
    {
        // File launched
    }
    else
    {
        // File launch failed
    }
});
```

Comment: That's fine when launching a specific PDF from the app. But what about hyperlinks to other PDFs from within a launched PDF? These are simple hyperlinks in Adobe Javascript. I cannot code these like I would in the app. I'm thinking that the Edge App in this case would need to be packaged with the correct PDFs in its library for the hyperlinks to work? Thoughts??

Comment: What do you mean the hyperlinks to other PDFs? The PDF file has a default  app to open it. In UWP, you can open it by the other app that do not change the default app.